# Глагол со значением «иметь насморк»

Tags: лексика, значение-слов, переводы

Если я правильно понимаю, немецкий глагол *schnupfen* значит «иметь насморк». Можно ли перевести его на русский язык также одним глаголом?

Кажется, что-то похожее обозначает глагол *сопливить*, но в словаре Ефремовой он истолкован как «пачкать соплями».

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В повседневной речи глагол `сопливить` чаще используется именно в значении `«иметь насморк»`.
Ваш вопрос меня заинтересовал, и я провёл мини-опрос на работе на тему `"значение слова сопливить"`. Как итог: все 23 опрошенных респондента истолковали глагол именно как `"иметь насморк"`, `"болеть насморком"`.

Answer (score 4):

Словари дают [СОПЛИВЕТЬ](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&bts=x&ro=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%8C):
СОПЛИВЕТЬ, -вею, -веешь; нсв. Разг. Быть сопливым; становиться сопливым; простудиться.

А вот СОПЛИВИТЬ - это «пачкать соплями».

Comment: Боюсь, это орфографические варианты, но информация интересная!

Comment: Думаю, разные суффиксы придают слову разный смысл. Примеры: молодить - молодеть; зеленить - зеленеть.

Comment: а вы уверены, что *молодИть — молодЕть* это тот же случай, что и *соплИвить — соплИветь*? В одном случае позиция сильная, в другом — слабая.

Comment: к тому же, Кузнецов не сделал отдельную статью для *сопливить* и в орфографическом словаре его тоже нет.

Comment: Не уверен, это только предположение.